# KeyCloak with Custom DB. Is it possible to back keycloak with cutom-db without keep syncing it with KeyCloak DB?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-services

Is it possible to use keycloak with custom DB? E.g. we have a database where we have all the users and their password. Can we use keycloak with that database or do we need to add each user to keycloak and have to keep our-user-db and keycloak-db in sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES. In `User Federation`, you can add LDAP or kerberos with Keycloak supported. And you can develop custom User Federation.

[Custom Provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#custom-providers) tells you can achieve your goal. But from [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#migrating-from-an-earlier-user-federation-spi)， it says you can migrate from **early** User Federation SPI. This User Federation SPI can be created in Keycloak 2.4.0 with the APIs at that version. On keycloak website, I just find [1.9.0](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/1.9/server_development_guide/topics/user-federation.html), it says there's a provider/federation-provider sample you can refer. Maybe you can try to find 2.4.0 bundle and sample to do your work.

After you create your User Federation SPI, then you refer [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#migrating-from-an-earlier-user-federation-spi) to migrate. You can choose to import or non-import.